# JointJs: How to define different customisation of ports into a group (in/out)

Tags: port, jointjs

I'm using JointJS to create my customised Elements which inherits from joint.shapes.devs.Model

My element is a rectangle with one in port and two out ports.
I want the output ports to be filled with different colours (one green and red the other).

I know how to define different colours for in ports and out ports. But, how could I define different colours for ports in the out group?

This is mi actual code

```
joint.shapes.devs.Model.define('presence.BasicStepModel',
        {
            size: { width: stepW, height: stepW },
            ports: {
                groups: {
                    'in': {
                        attrs: {
                            circle: { opacity: 1 },
                            '.port-body': {
                                fill: '#20A0C0',
                                magnet: 'passive',
                                r: 6
                            },
                            '.port-label': {
                                opacity: 0
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'out': {
                        attrs: {
                            circle: { opacity: 1 }, //El "circle" es un elemento SVG describe el puerto que tiene forma circular
                            '.port-body': { //el "port-body" es una clase CSS
                                fill: '#60E040',
                                r: 6
                            },
                            '.port-label': {
                                opacity: 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            inPorts: ['inPort'],
            outPorts: ['outPort1', 'outPort2'] 
        }, {
            attrs: {
                '.label': { x: .5, 'font-family': "sans-serif", 'font-size': "12px", length: '12em' },//Si no uso el label como identificador de clase, no se ve bien
                '.bottom': { text: '', 'ref-y': 70 },
                '.topp': { 'ref-y': -20, opacity: 0 },
                '.rightt': { 'ref-y': 25, x: '50px', 'text-anchor': 'left', opacity: 1 },
                '.body': { fill: '#DEDFEF', rx: 5, ry: 5, },
                '.stepImage': { 'xlink:href': "./images/addCallData.png", width: imageW, height: imageW, x: 5, y: 5 }
            }
        }, {

        }, {
        }
    );
```